# r.viewshed.cva GRASS GIS 7.0.3

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0, add-ons

I am having problems with r.viewshed.cva in GRASS GIS 7.0.3 and 7.0.4. I run the addon with the DEM and 100 random vector points as input. The vector points are composed by the cat, and X and Y colum with coordinates. Finally I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/script
s/r.viewshed.cva.py", line 174, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/script
s/r.viewshed.cva.py", line 140, in main
    if flags['k'] and options["name_col"] is not '':
KeyError: 'name_col'

My laptop is a Core i7, Windows 10.

Comment: Could be something with the paths in the error message, both / and \ in same paths

Comment: mmm. but I don't know if it's something that I can solve.

Comment: Note that the routine is constrained to points in the current geographic region.
Calculating viewshed for location 542525.84871155,4760171.41381201 (point name = 1
)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Roaming\GRASS7\addons/script
s/r.viewshed.cva.py", line 174, in <module>
    main()

Comment: And now, it says Note that the routine is constrained to points in the current geographic region.
Calculating viewshed for location 538892.79570571,4756461.28637303 (point name = 1
)
WARNING: Illegal filename <vshed_1
>. Character <
> not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the [region](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.region.html) Before running viewshed? Maybe its trying to perform viewshed where you have no dem data?

You can set region in menu Settings-Region-Set region. You can also use a command line. To set to your DEM raster use command `g.region rast=elevation.dem`, replace elevation.dem with raster name

Comment: I have already set the region, but seems to not be that the problem

Comment: Did you try to install it from the console? 

    g.extension r.viewshed.cva

Answer (score 1):

The addon was broken and should be fixed now. For running it on Windows please wait for tomorrow to install the updated version. For these cases you might consider asking on grass-users mailing list where you usually get faster response.